# Regular expression for (digit/digit)

Tags: java, regex, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking for a regular expression for
         `(digit/digit)`, like `(1/2)`

Digit has to be 1-3 numbers. I use Java.

I think my problem is deeper than just regular expression. I can't get this working

```
   String s ="(1/15)";
   Assert.isTrue(s.contains("\\d{1,3}/\\d{1,3}"));
```

The test fails, even thought it should contain the required text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://rubular.com/r/0TYsAnxTu9)

```
\(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}\)
```

In java you have to do

```
s.matches("\\(\\d{1,3}\\/\\d{1,3}\\)");
```

to check for the match (watch out for the [escape sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html))

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
\(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}\)
```

If you need to extract the digits you probably want to use

```
\((\d{1,3})\/(\d{1,3}\))
```